# Android: Custom application attributes, accessible by package manager?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

For work I maintain an internal 'market' where new app releases can be uploaded and downloaded. I also maintain a launcher that can select from our many apps and launch them (some are the same app 'branded' differently). I can currently populate this list with the package name and the version code, but I would also like to add in the SVN branch.

I was thinking about having a script that would add the branch info as XML either to the manifest as a custom attribute or as a separate XML file. Ideally, this could be accessible publicly by the PackageManager. Is this possible?

Alternatively, can I programmatically change the APK name? Then I could use "$name - $branch" as the new name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking about having a script that would add the branch info as XML either to the manifest as a custom attribute or as a separate XML file. Ideally, this could be accessible publicly by the PackageManager. Is this possible?

You have add a `<meta-data>` element to a component's element (e.g., `<activity>`) and access the metadata XML content via `PackageManager`:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful"
            android:resource="@xml/wakeful"/>
    </receiver>
```

The component would access the metadata through code like this:

```
PackageManager pm=ctxt.getPackageManager();
ComponentName cn=new ComponentName(ctxt, getClass());
ActivityInfo ai=pm.getReceiverInfo(cn, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
XmlResourceParser xpp=ai.loadXmlMetaData(pm, "com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful");
```

Your custom build process could then adjust the XML resource pointed to by `<meta-data>` to contain whatever you want.

> Alternatively, can I programmatically change the APK name?

You can name the APK file whatever you want on your hard drive, but I would not count on that name remaining intact through the installation process.

Comment: Very thorough and helpful answer. Regarding the APK name, I meant the application name.

Comment: @galaxyinfinite: If by "application name" you mean the value of the `android:name` attribute on `<application>`, you can certainly change that. Simplest would be to keep it as a string resource and update that resource (perhaps in its own file). That way, you don't have to fuss with `PackageManager` and can just call `getString(R.string.app_name)` (or whatever) to retrieve the value. Though, for that matter, you could just create a *new* string resource and leave the application name alone.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I don't believe that the `PackageManager` can access the strings of other apps. I need to be able to access this string from outside the application, so it seems that your `meta-data` solution is the best one.

Comment: @galaxyinfinite: Any app can access the resources of any other app, with a little work. That being said, `<meta-data>` is the most flexible option here.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Looks like `PackageManager#getResourcesForApplication` would do the trick if I decided to go that route

Comment: @CommonsWare is there way to add new entries to wakeful.xml using this approach?

Comment: @nish1013: You cannot modify the meta-data at runtime, if that is what you mean. `@xml/wakeful` refers to a resource; resources are read-only at runtime.